# page zooming/content overlaps

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a top div that is 50px in height and the width has to be the width of the entire browser window.
I'm setting the `width: 100%; but the problem is that when I zoom in the other content that is placed inside will overlap onto other.
I know that width:100%; will always be only as much as the screen in currently zoomed and that is why the content overlaps.

The position of this div is fixed.
I tried to set up the width with jQuery and it works, but then when zooming out the top div will not keep max available screen width.

```
(document).ready(function(){
    var widthT = $(window).width();
    $('#top_status').css("width", widthT);
});
```

The jQuery above is fine on zooming in, but not zoom out since the width had already been set and not changing.

I'm trying to acquire something that works somehow as the facebook top blue bar. That one stays in place very well regardless of zoom.

thx

Comment: Are you using some CSS ´position:fixed´ property?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "the content overlaps". You might want to create a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to replicate the problem. As far as I know, Facebook aren't doing anything fancy with their menu.

Comment: The div as I said its using a fixed positioning. The thing is that when I zoom in the inside content kinda breaks apart at some point.

Comment: this is a jsFddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/LRSAA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post a jsFiddle we could help with specific examples, but you should be able to take care of these issues with [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).  They'll let you have control over break points when resizing the window and make sure it looks good no matter what resolution the site is being viewed.

Here are some resources for media queries in navigation:

[A Responsive Design Approach for Navigation](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/responsive_design_approach_for_navigation/)

[Progressive And Responsive Navigation](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/13/progressive-and-responsive-navigation/)

[Convert a Menu to a Dropdown for Small Screens](http://css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown/)

[Create A Pure CSS Responsive Menu](http://www.jasondemeuse.com/blog/blog-article/create-a-pure-css-responsive-menu)

[Responsive drop down menu with CSS media queries & jQuery](http://www.justinwhall.com/responsive-drop-down-menu-with-css-media-queries-jquery/)

Even if you don't want to change the structure or turn it into a dropdown, you can use the same media queries to adjust the menu elements to make them fit anywhere.